# Function in /etc/bashrc is not passing quotes through variables

Tags: bash, sed, find

I am trying to write a bashrc function to add a safety check to the find command when it is paired with "-exec rm". This script cuts off everything beginning with "-exec rm" and replaces it with a "-print0" which is then passed over to sed to re-add missing quotes if the user uses a quoted experssion.

I am running into a issue where the quotes I am adding via sed are not being passed to the line with the execution of the find command.

Rewriting the find command and re-adding quotes:

```
FIND_VAR=$(echo "$@" | sed "s/-exec rm.*/-print0/g" | sed 's/\*.* / "&" /g' | sed 's/ "/"/g')
```

Running the find command with the modifications:

```
FIND_LIST=$(/bin/find $FIND_VAR | sed 's|\./| \./|g')
```

What I would like to accomplish is if the user types the following:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The command is re-written via the bashrc to run as:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | sed 's|\./| \./|g'
```

This generates a list of files each spaced out which is passed to a modified rm function:

```
./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./file3.txt ...
```

The full function is listed below for reference:

```
       function find () {
          if echo "$@" | grep -q '-exec rm' ; then
            echo "Found rm command as part of find"
            FIND_VAR=$(echo "$@" | sed "s/-exec rm.*/-print0/g" | sed 's/\*.* / "&" /g' | sed 's/ "/"/g')
            echo "/bin/find $FIND_VAR"
            FIND_LIST=$(/bin/find $FIND_VAR | sed 's|\./| \./|g')
            echo "$FIND_LIST"
            echo "rm$FIND_LIST"
          else
            /bin/find "$@"
          fi
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't put a command in a string. It will not work. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details and discussion.

You have the command in an array. Use it.

Walk the array, find the arguments you want to remove and remove them then add the arguments you want to add to the array and run the new command.